# Dont allow to override php.ini values for certain headers as a root

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, email

We are having this issues in shared hosting environment. FYI: Under shared hosting environment each user can have a php.ini in their folder to override the global settings.

There will be many users in /home/many-users/public_html/php.ini (here, he can override the values) 
Example: safe_mode = Off

I want certain headers in PHP.INI should not be changed or controlled by clients (who are /home/many-users/)

These following headers should not be overridden by any user in this /home/*

```
mail.add_x_header = On
mail.log = /var/log/phpmail.log
;smtp_port = 25
sendmail_path = /usr/local/bin/logging_sendmail
```

Please tell me how can I achieve this ?

Comment: We are using cagefs with phpselector and cloudlinux os

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file with the following content.

```
vim  /etc/cl.selector/global_php.ini

;smtp_port = 25
sendmail_path = /usr/local/bin/logging_sendmail

mail.add_x_header = On
mail.log = /var/log/phpmail.log
```

and then run this following command.
 /usr/sbin/cagefsctl --setup-cl-selector